# Is there a way to access a Sharepoint folder that has a password through the REST API using Python?

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365

I am attempting to access a locked Sharepoint folder from another organization that is shared with me. I have the password to access it online, however I am unable to access through Python. Have tried using my user and a client-id with the password as the client-secret.

Is there anyway to access it through python using only the password?

Expecting to have access to the files inside so I can export their contents to my data lake.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, there is no such rest api to get a folder with a password. And I feel regretful to inform you that it turns out to be a by-design one.